# Notion API Relation Property - How to get request

Tags: python, notion-api, notion

**Question:**
How to query Notion Relation Properties from a Notion Database using the Notion API?

**Context:**
I'm attempting to use Notion's API to query a database I've created. A few columns within the database are relation properties. I have made sure to share the relation properties (related databases) with my Notion "integration". I can successfully query all the database columns, but for the columns that are relation properties, the query responds with an "id".

This [resource](https://developers.notion.com/reference/property-object#relation) from Notion makes it seem like I should be receiving synced_property_name    in the response. I am conscious I could be reading this wrong.

**What am I trying to do:**
Eventually, I'd like to be able to write a new record to the main database. I'm experimenting with get requests to make sure I am using the relation property appropriately. I think what I'll need to do is to separately query all the relational databases, and use the "ID" to write any related record in the new database.